# How to query mongodb on a specific field

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection of objects with the following schema :

```
   var Meetup = new Schema({
  name: String,
  text:String,

});
```

I would like to get all of the meetups whom name contain a string.

Here is my api :

```
module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

and in my angular controller i have :

```
 var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');
$scope.meetups = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });
```

can anyone help

Comment: Check this question if it solves your question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880521/data-binding-to-a-specific-item-of-an-array-in-angular][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query on specific field

```
ModelName.find({fieldName: value}, function (err, results) {
    //...
  });
```

so for your case query will be like:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({name: req.query.name}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
};
```

and angular controller like

```
var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups', {}, {
  query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
});

$scope.meetups = []

Meetup.query({name: 'yourName'}).$promise.then(function(results) {
   // console.log(results);
   $scope.meetups = results;
}, function(error) {
  // console.log(error);
   $scope.meetups = [];
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i want to know how to specify the value on the front end